Correct form of Richard's curve (generalized logistic function)
I'm studying logistic functions these days.
I came across generalized logistic function (Richard's curve) on Wikipedia here:[Generalised logistic function][1]
However, I cannot find any article that proposed Richard's curve in this form:
$$
Y(t) = A + { K-A \over (C + Q e^{-B(t - M)}) ^ {1 / \nu} }
$$
I'm wondering from which scientific article I can find this equation or anything similar.
Thanks!
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function

https://www.jstor.org/stable/23686557

Hi Claude, thanks for the reply. However, I think the original Richard's article didn't give this form of generalized logistic function
